# Training/using the BiGG detector

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to evaluate the REIN framework. As a starting point, I am trying to replicate some of the results presented in [REIN - A Fast, Robust, Scalable REcognition INfrastructure](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/icra11.pdf)
. First, I am trying to get the BiGG detector trained and running, but I am having problems. I followed [the tutorial on training and using BiGG](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bigg_detector/Tutorials/How%20to%20train%20and%20use%20the%20BiGG%20object%20detector?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22bigg_detector/Tutorials/How+to+train+and+use+the+BiGG+object+detector%22). I trained the detector on 4 objects using the "manually selected 3D bounding box" method. This created 4 files in the database/models/BiGG/ subdirectory. The files are a few hundred KB each (I don't know if that's expected).

The trouble begins when I try running the BiGG detector. It seems to load all 4 models ok, then notifies that it starts doing detections. Next, the bigg detection nodelet continuously outputs the line `Detections: 9` regardless of what's in front of the camera, doesn't publish anything on /bigg/detections, and **starts consuming more and more RAM at a rate of ~30-40MB/sec until all the system RAM is depleted**.

I think the REIN framework looks very promising, so I would really appreciate help getting some of the detectors such as BiGG running so that I can try REIN out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10275/training/using-the-bigg-detector/) by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

REIN is not being developed anymore. We are working on a non-ROS specific version of it. Previous object recognition pipelines (like BIGG) will be ported back to it once stable. A release is expected for July/August 2011.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1